# How to clear a search field value and query result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algolia

So here is the situation,

- In header area there is a search field and a close icon
- Typing anything in the search field generates results in the body area of the page.
- Clicking the Close icon should clear the search field's value as well as the results shown in the body area of the page.
- I have used val() and attr() to clear the search field value but this unfortunately doesn't clear the search result shown in the body area of the page and this is because the search query isn't cleared, below is the code example:

**Before Searching, Website URL**

```
www.website.com/phones-accessories
```

**After Searching, Website URL**

```
www.website.com/phones-accessories#q=HTC&idx=magento_default_products&p=0&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Phones%20%26%20Accessories&is_v=1
```

If I remove **HTC** from **q=HTC** then the page removes the search result from the body area of the page which is exactly what I want to do, so please let me know if there is a jQuery way to do this which would work across different website address.

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not make sense without the code to support it. Please read [mcve]

Comment: I think it's straight forward, why changing the val() and attr() doesn't change the search query?

Comment: Great you think it is straight forward, then you do not need to ask the question ;) If you want answers here, show some code that will clarify what you are trying. Perhaps you just need plain JS to split the parameters

Comment: :) I meant it is straight forward to those who understand how query results are displayed dynamically in page, as I mentioned earlier I just want to clear the search fields value to null, they are using Algolia script and I am not sure where the code is that triggers the search function.